# Equal spacing for figures and listings

Tags: spacing, floats, listings, captions

I want to include figures and listings in my document and I want them to have the same spacings to text and captions.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,parskip,oneside,ngerman,headsepline]{scrbook}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{captionpos=b,frame=single}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some caption}]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}

Some text

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

Some rext
\end{document}
```

The result is following (I added boxes to show the spacing).

[image: Spacings]

1. As you can see, the red boxes have the same spacing.
   How can I make the spacing start above/below the frame?
2. The spacing below the figure is bigger than the listing.
   How can I make them the same?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15925 help you?  Note that as standard some of these separations include stretchable glue rather than being fixed lengths.

Comment: Thanks. The other thread you posted does not really me as there is no information on the difference between figure and listing. Also the spacings between figure/listing caption and text are always the same, but different between figure and listing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the caption is below the float contents, you can adjust the following caption parameters through `\captionsetup`:

- `aboveskip` (space between the float contents and the caption)
- `belowskip` (space after the caption)

The default values are, for `scrbook` class, `aboveskip=10pt` and `belowskip=0pt`. Also, a `\baselineskip` is added by default before the floating object and `1.2\baselineskip` after it, IIRC.

The above settings don't work for listings. But you can similarly set these parameters for listings through `\lstset`:

- `abovecaptionskip` (space between the float contents and the caption)
- `belowcaptionskip` (space after the caption)
- `aboveskip` (space between the float contents and the preceding text)
- `belowskip` (space between the float contents and the following text)

So leaving `figure` parameters untouched and adding in your `\lstset` something like

```
abovecaptionskip=10pt,belowcaptionskip=0pt,aboveskip=\baselineskip,belowskip=1.2\baselineskip
```

should do what you want.

Complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %option demo only for the example
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  captionpos=b,
  frame=single,
  abovecaptionskip=10pt,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowskip=1.2\baselineskip
  }

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some caption}]
Some code
\end{lstlisting}

Some text

\begin{figure}[H]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image.png}
    \caption{Some caption}
    \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

Some rext
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

You can adjust these values if you think they don't meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But I have a few additional question to that. 1) How would I change the skip after a float object? 2) Why do those two caption settings not work for listings, as font e.g. works? 3) What does IFIRC mean?

Comment: @mklnwt 1) add `belowskip=<lenght>` in `\captionsetup`; 2) listings are not contemplated as floats in document classes but added by the `listings` package; 3) a typo... it was meant to be IIRC (if I remember correctly)

Comment: To 1): I meant to reduce the skip, like to set it to \baselineskip instead of 1.2\baselineskip

Comment: @mklnwt `belowskip=-.2\baselineskip`

Comment: @mklnwt Glad to help.