# Equal spacing for Listings, Tables, Figures and Equations

Tags: spacing, floats, equations, listings, tabularx

I'm searching for a MWE to get equal distances between text and all environments in my document.

Equal distances mean in this case:

1. Distance between text and the upper border of the environment
2. Distance between caption and text

In the attached MWE, you can see that there are always other distances. So how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,twoside=false,]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{isodate,babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext} % Just for the MWE

\DeclareCaptionType{equ}[][]
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

%Listing with and without minipage environment
\blindtext
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b,caption={[Listing]{Listing}}]
Code Code Code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b,caption={[Listing]{Listing}}]
Code Code Code
\end{lstlisting}
\blindtext
\newpage
%Tabularx environment
\blindtext
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|p{33mm}|l|>{\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
\endfirsthead
Test & Test & Test & Test\\ 
\hline 
\caption[Tabularx]{Tabularx}
\end{tabularx}
\blindtext
\newpage
%Figure environment
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
\caption{Figure}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\newpage
%Equation environment
\blindtext
\begin{equ}[!ht]
\begin{equation}
a=b+c
\end{equation}
\caption{Caption of the equation}
\end{equ}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This question seems to be similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148168/equal-spacing-for-figures-and-listings) one, but asks for more environments.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? Currently, it isn't since `Example.json` is not available.

Comment: @leandriis Sorry, did it now!

Comment: Fixing this vertical distances is not good idea. They normally contain stretchable glue which enables that (La)TeX can nice format of document pages.

Comment: @Zarko Okay... but could you give me a hint how to achieve the same spaces for listings with and without a minipage?

Comment: That is my biggest issue so far...

Comment: Why you like to enclose listings in `minipage`? Do you have some special reason? From MWE i don't see this. I wouldn't put `listing` in  `minipage`.

Comment: I need the `minipage` to prevent line breaks within the listings.

Comment: This is (typographically) wrong approach. Listing is deliberately designed so that can be split over more pages.  If it is inside `minipage` , `minipage` can leave a lot of empty spaces on previous page (when is moved to the next page) . However i such a cases you cam manually correct vertical distances, for example as: `\begin{minipage}t]\linewidth}\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
\begin{lstlisting}[captionpos=b,caption={[Listing]{Listing}}]
Code Code Code
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
`

Comment: Thanks for your reply even if it is the wrong approach :) I have often used the way you suggested but I would like to know the _exact_ value for the `\vspace{}` command. Is there a macro with defines the space skip of the minipage?

Comment: or simply left out option `[t]` at `minipage`.  You will have to wait for an expert to answer your .

Comment: Perfect! Thats a way in the right direction! Now the spaces are to small but equal!